# Which browser is easier to develop plug-ins for? Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: firefox, plugins, browser, google-chrome

I'd like to develop a small plug-in for web browsers, namely Chrome and FireFox.  Which one is easier† to develop for a first projet?  I am very unfamiliar with this space as I spend most of my days coding server-side Java.

†: Easier in my context means:

- shallow learning curve
- least amount of additional tooling *required*
- a Java like syntax, i.e.: JavaScript
- solid API documentation

If it matters, here is the goal of my plug-in:

- find an image tag in a page with a specific tag.  Example: `<img src="bobisyouruncle.jpg" findme="found" />`
- send the image to my remote RESTful web service
- overlay an image onto the above image (or replace it)
- allow simple configuration and storage for authentication against the web service

Answers from folks with direct experience coding for both browsers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: To those voting to close as opinion-based: That reason is only supposed to be used for question which are **primarily** opinion based. Questions which can be answered primarily based on "expert experience, facts, references, or specific expertise" do not qualify for that reason. This question can be answered based on that criteria.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Chrome.  It has a fast and easy learning curve.  Start here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html .  The built in development tools allows you to [debug your own code in a matter of a click](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup).  And ctrl+r actually refreshes your extension code.

Firefox extensions are much more complex and harder to develop.  You will need to set up a development environment with many custom settings and "developer's extensions" and it will be very hard to actually debug your code.

**Update:** an interesting real-world blog post comparing Chrome, FireFox and Opera extension building: http://blog.nparashuram.com/2011/10/writing-browser-extensions-comparing.html

Comment: +1: thanks for presenting an answer with details

Comment: Is this still the case in July 2014?

Comment: my main concern is that I need access to the file system, with Chrome I noticed a box on some extensions that says "allow file urls", so as long as I click this box when I install my extension - the extension should be able to access the local file system? I need to write text files - if I can't totally control the folder path that is ok as long as I can acess this path from outside the browser using other applications.

Comment: @ycomp: please start a new question for that

Comment: googles documentation has such a condescending tone to it I can hardly read it.  Ok kiddies here we go don't be scared of the big words.  You can do it boys and girls.  Aren't you special.  Awwww gee.  etc.  Ugh!

Answer (score 1):

Firefox's new [WebExtension API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) means that extensions written for Chrome *should*, for the most part, work in Firefox with minimal changes.

I found this question when researching how to start developing extensions, so I haven't had a chance to work with anything yet, so YMMV.